# Should a Kafka Consumer be a part of Django Web Layer or a separate service?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, apache-kafka

I have a Django application which has a Kafka integration to process some orders.
The topics on the Kafka queue are created dynamically so the consumers has also to be subscribed dynamically.
Now when I initialise a consumer it goes to block the main thread so I have to start the consumer in a background thread, but I am not able to see any print statements so I am not sure if the consumer is initialized, also if this is the right approach to do so ?

```
def kafka_consumer(topic) :
  try :
    if topic is None :
        raise Exception("Topic is none, unable to initialize kafka consumer")
    conf = {'bootstrap.servers': "localhost:9092", 'group.id': 'test', 'session.timeout.ms': 6000,
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'}
    c = Consumer(conf)
    print("Subscribing consumer to topic ",topic[0])
    c.subscribe(topic)
    # Read messages from Kafka, print to stdout
    try:
        while True:
            msg = c.poll(timeout=1.0)
            if msg is None:
                continue
            if msg.error():
                raise KafkaException(msg.error())
            else:
                sys.stderr.write('%% %s [%d] at offset %d with key %s:\n' %
                                    (msg.topic(), msg.partition(), msg.offset(),
                                    str(msg.key())))
                try :
                    print(json.loads(msg.value()))
                    print("---------------------------------")
                    objs = serializers.deserialize("json", msg.value())
                    for obj in objs :
                        print(obj)
                        print(obj.object)
                except Exception as e :
                    import traceback
                    print(traceback.format_exc())
    except Exception as e:
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())
    finally:
        c.close()
except Exception as e:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Below is how I am calling the function :

```
try :
        topic = []
        topic.append(offer.offering_order_id)
        background_thread = Thread(target=kafka_consumer, args=(topic))
        background_thread.start()
    except Exception as e :
        import traceback
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Can someone help me with the Architecture please?

Comment: Having dynamic topics seems like a bad idea... What data are you sending here?

Comment: Note: rather than multithreading yourself, you could look at the aiokafka library

Comment: The data are basically, buy orders, so for each kind of offerings(read unique addresses) I create a topic, so orders from different topics can be processed parallel, once the offerings are not live anymore, I plan to delete the topic.

Comment: What defines "livliness"? Sounds like you just want a pub-sub queue, not necessarily a persistent log like Kafka. And you can have one `buy-orders` topic with 100+ partitions, for example, if you care about parallelism